# Writing the general term of a sequence without double factorials

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus

Here's a question I was assigned:

Find the general term without using double factorials:

$$1+\frac{1\cdot2}{1\cdot3}+\frac{1\cdot2\cdot3}{1\cdot3\cdot5}+\frac{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4}{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7}+...$$

I have no clue how to even approach this without using a double factorial?

Comment: Do you mean "sequence" or "series"?

Comment: What makes you think this would require a double factorial?

Comment: @terrace expressions such as $1\times 3\times 5\times\cdots\times(2n-1)$ are often written as $(2n-1)!!$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$1\times3\times5\times\cdots\times(2n-1)
=\frac{1\times 2\times 3\times\cdots\times (2n)}{2\times 4\times 6\times\cdots\times(2n)}$$
etc.

Comment: how does it help

Comment: The expression $1\times 3\times\cdots\times(2n-1)$ appears in the denominators of the sum.

Comment: I really don't see why your (good) answer received a downvote. One more mystery !

Comment: @terrace ... re-writing Lord Shark's equation, we get $$(2n-1)!! = \frac{(2n)!}{2^n \cdot n!}$$